# Get value inside NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My codes doesnt work, do you have an idea why? I want to display some data to my UITable from the requested HTTP

```
class contactView : UITableViewController{
    var values: NSMutableArray!

@IBOutlet var tbview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    if(signed != 1){
        self.navigationItem.title = ""
    }else{

        let outbtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign out", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(contactView.out_action))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = outbtn

        let reloadData = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reload", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(contactView.loadData))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = reloadData

        //Check Connection

        if(reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true) {
            loadData()
        }else{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error Connection", message: "Not Internet Connection", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
            let alertAct = UIAlertAction(title: "I'll connect later !", style: .Destructive){
                (actions) -> Void in
            }
            alert.addAction(alertAct)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
func loadData(){
    let url = NSURL(string: url_friends)

    let to_post = "user=iam&pin=101218"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = to_post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (let data,let response,let error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            do{
                self.values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
                print(self.values)

            }catch{
                print(error)
                return
            }
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I want to display the variable "value" data in my table but error keep occuring, saying it is nil when call in my table function cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellidentity") as UITableViewCell!
  let mainData = values[indexpath.row] as! String
  let x = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

  if(signed != 1){
      print("No people")
  }else{
      let x = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
      x.text = mainData["name"]

  }
  return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
let x : Int
    if(reachability.signed() != 1){
        x = 1
    }else{
        x = values.count        
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you are using `UITableViewController`, there's no need to create your own `tbView` outlet. The table view controller already has a property called `tableView`, which has a reference to the table view. The only time you need to create your own outlet is if you're subclassing `UIViewController` (i.e. you're not dealing with table view controller, but rather standard view controller that just happens to have a table view somewhere on its `view`.

Comment: @Rob thankyou Rob I'd changed now the codes, removing the outlet

Comment: OK. But that's can't be your real `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because it won't compile because there is no variable `indexpath`, only `indexPath`. Also, if `mainData` is a `String` (e.g. `let mainData = values[indexPath.row] as! String`), then you can't use subscript operator (e.g. `mainData["name"]`). Perhaps you meant to say that `mainData` was a dictionary (e.g. `let mainData = values[indexPath.row] as! [String: String]`)?!? That's what I assumed below.

Comment: I just dont know how to handle table Functions on viewDidLoad

Comment: See my answer below. Basically, treat `values` like the optional it really is, and do safe optional binding or other tests to see if the optional is `nil` or not.

Comment: @Rob thanks, I really appreciate your answer, it is now finally working

Comment: @Rob thanks, I now checked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first time you load the table, it would be `nil`. The `dataTaskWithRequest` completion block has to explicitly call `self.tableview.reloadData()`, to tell the table to update itself now that the network request has finished. Remember, `dataTaskWithRequest` runs asynchronously, meaning that it finishes *after* the table is already presented. So you have to tell the table to reload itself (and therefore call the `UITableViewDataSource` methods again).

So you probably want something like:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {  data, response, error in
    guard data != nil && error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    do {
        if let values = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSMutableArray {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.value = values
                print(values)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        } 
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Note, before doing forced unwrapping of `data` with `data!`, I first guard to make sure it's not `nil`. Never use `!` unless you've know it cannot possibly be `nil`.

---

In terms of why your `UITableView` methods are failing the first time they're called, it's because they're relying upon `reachability.signed()` or `signed`. But the real question is whether `values` is `nil` or not.

So, perhaps:

```
var values: NSMutableArray?    // make this a standard optional, not an implicitly unwrapped one

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellidentity") as UITableViewCell!
    let x = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel    // btw, using `UITableViewCell` subclasses are more elegant than using cryptic `tag` numbers

    if let mainData = values?[indexPath.row] as? [String: String] {
        x.text = mainData["name"]
    } else {
        print("No people")
        x.text = "(retrieving data)"  // perhaps you want to tell the user that the request is in progress
    }
    return cell
}

// if `values` is `nil`, return `1`, otherwise returns `values.count`

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values?.count ?? 1
}
```

Your code was configured to return one cell if the data was not available, so I've repeated that here, but generally I return zero rows if there's no data. If you do that, it simplifies `cellForRowAtIndexPath` even more, as it doesn't have to even worry about the "no data" condition at all. But that's up to you.

Now, I've made some assumptions above (e.g. that `mainData` was really a dictionary given that you are subscripting it with a string `"name"`). But less important than these little details is the big picture, namely that one should scrupulously avoid using `!` forced unwrapping or using implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you know with absolute certainty that the underlying optional can never be `nil`.

Comment: Thankyou, but how about on the table function side, error keep occuring because they are the one to call first.

Comment: Right. So you have to write your `UITableViewDataSource` so that they gracefully handle both scenarios, when they're called before the data has been received and again after the data comes in (and you called `tableView.reloadData()`).

Comment: What do your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods look like? Edit your question to show that code. That's where you need to handle the case where there is initially no data to display, and then later, after the URL session's completion method has been called.

Comment: @duncanC thankyou, I edit my question now and show the numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Get rid of the "!" in the declaration of your values array. You need to write your data source methods to handle the case where the values array has not finished loading yet. You could make values non-optional and set it to an empty array in your view controller's init method, or make it optional and write your data source methods to handle the nil case.

Comment: A data source array is a concrete object. It is supposed to be never `nil` – as the corresponding table view of a table view controller is never `nil`. Always declare it as an empty, non-optional array of the appropriate type. If the received data is `nil` remove all objects.

Comment: @vadian - I respectfully disagree. The entire purpose of optionals is to designate when the variable has not yet been set. This a perfect use case for an optional. (And, in fact, you sometimes have to differentiate the "the data hasn't been retrieved" and "we retrieved data and there is nothing to show", and an optional captures this distinction without needing to add a new state variable.)

Comment: I understand your argument but from the point of view of the (non-optional) table view there is either data to show (data source array not empty) or no data to show (data source array empty). A *physically* existing table view has no *optional* state. Further I've never seen an optional data source array in any sample code of Apple.

Comment: @vadian - I hear you, but simply fundamentally disagree. IMHO, this is a perfect use case for an optional, namely that you have some variable that simply hasn't been set yet. This is what optional we're designed for. If you're so inclined, you could always post your own answer outlining what you think the data source implementation should look like, and the community can vote as they see fit. But I'm getting the impression that there's no point in our debating it further here in comments, as it sounds like we're unlikely to convince each other.

Comment: Weighing in, I agree with Rob. Optionals were designed to represent the "variable not yet set" state, and that is a perfect match for this case.

Comment: Last reply: A table view data source array is supposed to be set – as empty array – during initialization. Once again, as far as I know Apple has never suggested an optional data source array for a designed non-optional table view.

Comment: First, Apple has never discussed this specific topic in detail, AFAIK, so I'd hesitate to draw any strong conclusions one way or the other on that. Second, the table view _is_ an optional, albeit, an implicitly unwrapped one. Third, what Apple has been very specific about, though, is that in Swift there is a difference between "there is a value" (which, in the case of an array, could be an empty array) and "there is no value" (which is an optional that is `nil`). They specifically advise against using magical values (e.g. an empty array) to designate that the value has not yet been set.